# PSGI, LWP::UserAgent & PayPal IPN

Tags: perl, paypal, paypal-ipn, lwp, psgi

I have been trying for some time to get a simple PayPal IPN module working but keep getting a 400 Bad Request error from LWP::UserAgent. I am not sure why this is happening. PayPal pings me fine (I'm using the IPN simulator) and I can see the process in my app logs. I can call the PayPal validation URL via LWP::UserAgent without form content and that works fine, but once I include the request content for validation I get error 400. If anyone knows about this please let me know.

-$self->{'_req'} is of type [Plack::Request](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aRequest)

```
my $url     = $test ? $VERIFY_URL_DEV : $VERIFY_URL;
my $ua      = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $req     = new HTTP::Request('POST', $url);
my $query   = 'cmd=_notify-validate&' . $self->{'_req'}->raw_body;

$req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$req->content( $query );

my $res = $ua->request($req);

if ($res->is_error)
{
    # HTTP error, indicate an invalid notification.
    warn "There was an error validating this IPN.";
    warn $res->message;
    warn $res->error_as_HTML;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set up a working and failing request object each and provide dumps with [as_string](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Request#r-as_string). Redact any non-public data.

Comment: There was a PayPal issue that provided an HTTP 400 error for Sandbox IPNs up until Monday night. Could you advise if the error is still occurring or if all is well?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the PayPal side. When I tested in sandbox, not the IPN simulator, it worked fine. That was very frustrating.